# Is there a way to mock backend response for Front End?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, mocking

I need these abilities.

- Track Requests being made and their responses.
- Put Request on modification filter which would either modify the request header/body and/or response's header/body for a certain url.
- Be able to specify how closely to match request to apply modification (i.e. if url matches vs all headers matches vs body matches too).
- Replay requests.
- Intercept and modify on live. Save Requests.

I wish postman could do it.

I have not been able to find chrome extension that does this. Most allow to modify header not body of request and none allow to mock response data.

I am open to terminal tools or stand alone tools.

Also assume i dont have control over backend at all or at the moment.

This can be called stubbing api response as well.

Comment: See [`ServiceWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker)

Comment: I wonder how https requests can be mocked and intercepted

Comment: What do mean by "mocked"? To test locally? Have you reviewed linked pages at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker ?

Comment: to fake response from server by intercepting requests and instead responding with customer defined response. and yes i have known about service worker, i dont have full control over backend so i can' really include them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) is what you're looking for. It lets you perform response [rewrites](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/rewrite/) on the fly, in addition to a whole bunch of other really useful things.

it's a paid application, but does have a free trial period.